# Planning for a faculty position in the USA

Tags: united-states, career-path, faculty-application

I have a PhD in education from a US university (ranked within top 20 public universities) in 'mathematics education'. Because of my scholarship requirements, I had to come back to my country. However, I am seriously thinking about going back to the USA (or an English speaking country) within 4-5 years.

As far as I understand, publishing 2-3 peer-reviewed journal articles per year will create a good resume (in total, 15-20 articles). I will hopefully apply to 1-2 grants for my projects, too.  I am currently an educator (educating math teacher candidates) at a university in my country. When the time comes, I am planning to apply to a faculty position at an average university in the USA (preferably a research university).

What do you think about my chances to get a faculty position if I accomplish these goals? How much advantage will my diploma give me?
Do you have any recommendations to increase my chances? and What kind of universities would likely accept my application?

I know it is a little early but I want to make sufficient preparations. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I did not vote to close... but I don't have any good advice, and I doubt that there is any genuinely good advice that can be given. Namely, the academic job market in the U.S. is currently very bad/tight, the Covid pandemic is making economics worse, and it appears not to be over... And competing with people in the U.S. with U.S. academic experience is an up-hill battle. Your U.S. PhD helps... If you can publish in journals that U.S. people publish in... you'd _almost_ be on a level playing field. But the number of colleges and universities that are willing to consider...

Comment: ... interviewing/considering international candidates who are not physically present in the U.S. (and dealing with visa issues) is _not_ large. These comments are not an "answer", because I don't know what to recommend to have any reasonable hope of this working out for you, unfortunately. People have terrible difficulties in the academic job market when they're already here, etc. So, I'd worry about your chances, but you may as well _attempt_ it, if that's what you want, unless there's a way that a failed attempt will upset your bosses there... Sorry, no good advice.

Comment: Thanks @paulgarrett. I don't know what the situation of job market will look like after 4-5 years but I want to work in an English speaking country anyway, preferably USA. Getting a job at a teaching-based university seems relatively easier to get an acceptance but the university must provide a rationale about why they want a foreigner. Considering tons of PhD graduates who can teach, I guess a low-ranked research-based university will be a better option in that regard.

Comment: @paulgarrett, on the contrary, I think it is _very_ good advice, though not an answer. Times are hard, but that doesn't mean you don't try.

Comment: Check CVs of people who have the type of job you want.  I suspect you will find most education faculty in the USA have experience teaching in primary or secondary schools in the USA.

Comment: "competing with people in the U.S. with U.S. academic experience is an up-hill battle." Could you explain why? I was considering taking a postdoc overseas but since I want to ultimately live in the US maybe I should reconsider.